# Ajax WP_Query reutrns no results on author.php

Tags: wp-query, ajax

I have an Ajax call for loading more posts on button click. The Ajax is generating a new WP_Query according to some arguments it gets from a form, then send the `posts` it gets back to the page.

It's working well on my home page and one of the taxonomy archives. I thought I've built it correctly in a way it would work anywhere, but apparently something is not going quite right on `author.php`. The code it not very thin ,I know, sorry.

JS:

```
$('.more-items-form.in-list').submit(ajaxMoreItems_list);

function ajaxMoreItems_list(e){

    e.preventDefault(); //prevent form normal submission

    var form = this; //the form
    ajaxUrl = $('input[name=ajax]',form).val(); //ajax url
    template = $('input[name=template]',form).val(); //template url
    tax = $('input[name=tax]',form).val(); //posts taxonomy
    term = $('input[name=term]',form).val(); //posts term
    author = $('input[name=author]',form).val(); //posts author
    ot = $('.more-items',form).text(); //original button text
    articles = $('.post-listing article').length; //number of loaded articles 

    /* start the ajax call */
    $.post(ajaxUrl, {
        template: template,
        action:'bayadaim_ajax_fetch_posts',
        offset: articles,
        ppp: 6,
        tax: tax,
        term: term,
        author: author,
        beforeSend : function(){
            $('.more-items',form).text('טוען...'); //change button text
            $('.more-items').prop('disabled',true); // Disable all more-items buttons to avoid mess, temp.
        }
    }).success(function(posts){
        $(posts).hide().appendTo('.post-listing').fadeIn(200); //print the items
        $('.more-items').not('fin').removeAttr('disabled'); //re-enable all more-items buttons

        if(!$.trim(posts)){
            $('.more-items',form).text('הסוף');
            $('.more-items',form).addClass('fin');
            $('.more-items',form).prop('disabled',true);
        }else{
            $('.more-items',form).text(ot); //reset the button text
            $('.more-items',form).removeAttr('disabled'); //re-enable all more-items buttons
        }

    }).error(function(){
        alert("שגיאה בטעינת נתונים, בבקשה נסו שנית.");
    }).complete(function(){

    });
```

PHP:

```
    /** fetch more POSTS with ajax **/
    function bayadaim_ajax_fetch_posts(){
        $template = $_POST['template'];
        $offset = $_POST["offset"];
        $ppp = $_POST["ppp"];
        $tax = $_POST["tax"];
        $term = $_POST["term"];
        $meta = $_POST["meta"];
        $author = $_POST["author"];
        $orderby = $_POST["orderby"];
        $order = $_POST["order"];
        $post_type = (!empty($_POST["post_type"]) ? $_POST["post_type"] : "post");
        header("Content-Type: text/html");

        $args = array(
            'meta_key' => $meta,
            'orderby' => $orderby,
            'order' => $order, 
            'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $tax,
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $term,
                ),
            ),
            'author' => $author,
            'offset' => $offset,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => $post_type
        );

        $loop = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($loop->have_posts()) :
            while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                if ( $template = "row" ) {
                    include( locate_template( 'content-post_in_row.php', false, false ) ); //by using include(locate_template()) combination i keep child-theme functionality while still passing variables to included file.
                }else{
                    include( locate_template( 'content-post_in_listing.php', false, false ) ); //by using include(locate_template()) combination i keep child-theme functionality while still passing variables to included file.               
                }
            endwhile;
        else :
            if ( !empty($loop) ) console($loop); //for debugging
        endif;

        exit; 
    }

    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_bayadaim_ajax_fetch_posts', 'bayadaim_ajax_fetch_posts'); 
    add_action('wp_ajax_bayadaim_ajax_fetch_posts', 'bayadaim_ajax_fetch_posts');
```

WP_Query array returned:

```
    WP_Query Object
(
    [query] => Array
        (
            [meta_key] => 
            [orderby] => 
            [order] => 
            [posts_per_page] => 6
            [tax_query] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [taxonomy] => 
                            [field] => slug
                            [terms] => 
                        )

                )

            [author] => 228
            [offset] => 6
            [post_status] => publish
            [post_type] => post
        )

    [query_vars] => Array
        (
            [meta_key] => 
            [orderby] => 
            [order] => DESC
            [posts_per_page] => 6
            [tax_query] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [taxonomy] => 
                            [field] => slug
                            [terms] => 
                        )

                )

            [author] => 228
            [offset] => 6
            [post_status] => publish
            [post_type] => post
            [error] => 
            [m] => 
            [p] => 0
            [post_parent] => 
            [subpost] => 
            [subpost_id] => 
            [attachment] => 
            [attachment_id] => 0
            [name] => 
            [static] => 
            [pagename] => 
            [page_id] => 0
            [second] => 
            [minute] => 
            [hour] => 
            [day] => 0
            [monthnum] => 0
            [year] => 0
            [w] => 0
            [category_name] => 
            [tag] => 
            [cat] => 
            [tag_id] => 
            [author_name] => 
            [feed] => 
            [tb] => 
            [paged] => 0
            [meta_value] => 
            [preview] => 
            [s] => 
            [sentence] => 
            [title] => 
            [fields] => 
            [menu_order] => 
            [embed] => 
            [category__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [category__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [category__and] => Array
                (
                )

            [post__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [post__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [post_name__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag__and] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag_slug__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag_slug__and] => Array
                (
                )

            [post_parent__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [post_parent__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [author__in] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 228
                )

            [author__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [ignore_sticky_posts] => 
            [suppress_filters] => 
            [cache_results] => 1
            [update_post_term_cache] => 1
            [lazy_load_term_meta] => 1
            [update_post_meta_cache] => 1
            [nopaging] => 
            [comments_per_page] => 5
            [no_found_rows] => 
        )

    [tax_query] => WP_Tax_Query Object
        (
            [queries] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [taxonomy] => 
                            [terms] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [field] => slug
                            [operator] => IN
                            [include_children] => 1
                        )

                )

            [relation] => AND
            [table_aliases:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [queried_terms] => Array
                (
                )

            [primary_table] => dq3q092o_posts
            [primary_id_column] => ID
        )

    [meta_query] => WP_Meta_Query Object
        (
            [queries] => Array
                (
                )

            [relation] => 
            [meta_table] => 
            [meta_id_column] => 
            [primary_table] => 
            [primary_id_column] => 
            [table_aliases:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [clauses:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [has_or_relation:protected] => 
        )

    [date_query] => 
    [request] => SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  dq3q092o_posts.ID FROM dq3q092o_posts  LEFT JOIN dq3q092o_term_relationships AS tr1 ON (dq3q092o_posts.ID = tr1.object_id) LEFT JOIN dq3q092o_term_taxonomy ON ( tr1.term_taxonomy_id = dq3q092o_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  0 = 1
) AND ( dq3q092o_posts.post_author IN (228)  AND dq3q092o_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((dq3q092o OR (dq3q092o_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'author' AND dq3q092o_term_taxonomy.term_id = '18'))_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY dq3q092o_posts.ID HAVING MAX( IF ( dq3q092o_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'author', IF (  dq3q092o_term_taxonomy.term_id = '18',2,1 ),0 ) ) <> 1  ORDER BY dq3q092o_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 6, 6
    [posts] => Array
        (
        )

    [post_count] => 0
    [current_post] => -1
    [in_the_loop] => 
    [comment_count] => 0
    [current_comment] => -1
    [found_posts] => 0
    [max_num_pages] => 0
    [max_num_comment_pages] => 0
    [is_single] => 
    [is_preview] => 
    [is_page] => 
    [is_archive] => 1
    [is_date] => 
    [is_year] => 
    [is_month] => 
    [is_day] => 
    [is_time] => 
    [is_author] => 1
    [is_category] => 
    [is_tag] => 
    [is_tax] => 1
    [is_search] => 
    [is_feed] => 
    [is_comment_feed] => 
    [is_trackback] => 
    [is_home] => 
    [is_404] => 
    [is_embed] => 
    [is_paged] => 
    [is_admin] => 1
    [is_attachment] => 
    [is_singular] => 
    [is_robots] => 
    [is_posts_page] => 
    [is_post_type_archive] => 
    [query_vars_hash:WP_Query:private] => 4ac5721966fc9ad057ab45f5aff3826f
    [query_vars_changed:WP_Query:private] => 
    [thumbnails_cached] => 
    [stopwords:WP_Query:private] => 
    [compat_fields:WP_Query:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => query_vars_hash
            [1] => query_vars_changed
        )

    [compat_methods:WP_Query:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => init_query_flags
            [1] => parse_tax_query
        )

)
```

**I've tried so far:**

1. changing the php arguments or deleting them all - same result
2. the submit button was originaly inside the main author.php loop, i've moved it out with no success.
3. I had a `pre_get_posts` hooked to the main author loop, I've deleted it to check if it conflicts - same same.

Thanks a lot,
Itamar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i figured it out somehow. There were two causes to that issue:

1. `tax_query` array values cannot be empty. it either the array keys are populated, or there shouldn't be an array at all.
2. I don't know why, but giving `author` a number didn't work. I've changed it to `'author__in' => array($author)` and it worked.

**The fixed code altogether:**

```
function bayadaim_ajax_fetch_posts(){
$template = $_POST['template'];
$offset = $_POST["offset"];
$ppp = $_POST["ppp"];
$tax = $_POST["tax"];
$term = $_POST["term"];

if( !empty($_POST["tax"]) || !empty($_POST["term"]) ){
$tax_query = array(array(
            'taxonomy' => $tax,
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $term,
        ),
    );
}else{
    $tax_query = null;
}
$meta = $_POST["meta"];
$author = $_POST["author"];
$orderby = $_POST["orderby"];
$order = $_POST["order"];
$post_type = (!empty($_POST["post_type"]) ? $_POST["post_type"] : "post");
header("Content-Type: text/html");

$args = array(
    'meta_key' => $meta,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'order' => $order, 
    'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
    'tax_query' => $tax_query,
    'author__in' => array($author),
    'offset' => $offset,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => $post_type
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);

if ($loop->have_posts()) :
    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        if ( $template == 'row' ) {
            include( locate_template( 'content-post_in_row.php', false, true ) ); //by using include(locate_template()) combination i keep child-theme functionality while still passing variables to included file.
        }elseif( $template == 'list' ){
            include( locate_template( 'content-post_in_listing.php', false, true ) ); //by using include(locate_template()) combination i keep child-theme functionality while still passing variables to included file.                
        }
    endwhile;
else :
    if ( !empty($loop) ) print_r($loop); //for debugging
endif;

exit; 
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_bayadaim_ajax_fetch_posts', 'bayadaim_ajax_fetch_posts'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_bayadaim_ajax_fetch_posts', 'bayadaim_ajax_fetch_posts');
```

Any suggestions for how to make the code more elegant and efficient are welcomed.